# Local variable x referenced before assignment - Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I must get data value from `POST` request and write it to `Word` document. But I'm getting error. How can I fix the problem ?

```
def military_document(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateMilitaryDocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES, use_required_attribute=False)
        if form.is_valid():
            group_degree = request.POST.get('group_degree')
            print(group_degree)
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Added successfully !')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('military_document')
    else:
        form = CreateMilitaryDocumentForm(use_required_attribute=False)
    doc = DocxTemplate("../document.docx")
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'group_degree': group_degree,
    }
    doc.render(context)
    doc.save("generated_doc.docx")
    return render(request, 'military_document.html', context)
```

Comment: I assume that variable is `group_degree`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, yes, sir.

Comment: in case of a GET request, you never assign something to `group_degree`, so what should `group_degree` be in `context = { ... }`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I'm so sorry, sir, but didn't get the answer.

Comment: If `request.method == 'POST'` then you set `group_degree` to `request.POST.get('group_degree')`. If `request.method` is *not* `'POST'` then you do not set `group_degree` to anything but you still try and use it in `context`. What value do you expect it to hold in that case?

Comment: @khelwood, but, I can get `group_degree` if and only if request is `POST`. If request is not `POST`, I don't want to do anything. In my case, I just want to write data to word page, that's all.

Comment: It is your code, inside `context = {...}`, that is trying to use `group_degree` *even if* the request is not a post. If you don't want to use it in that case, change your code so it doesn't try to use it.

Comment: @khelwood, I should use `group_degree` in `context`. Because the library that I use for filling Word page with datas, needs that datas in `context`.

Comment: You just said you can only get `group_degree` if the request is a post. So you can't put it in `context` if the request is *not* a post, because you don't have it. But that is what your current code is trying to do.

Comment: @khelwood, please help me, now I don't know what to do, and my company forces me really to do that in a few hour. Help me with code, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def military_document(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateMilitaryDocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES, use_required_attribute=False)
        if form.is_valid():
            group_degree = request.POST.get('group_degree')
            print(group_degree)
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Added successfully !')
            doc = DocxTemplate("../document.docx")
            context = {
                'group_degree': group_degree,
            }
            doc.render(context)
            doc.save("generated_doc.docx")
            return render(request, 'military_document.html', context)
    else:
        form = CreateMilitaryDocumentForm(use_required_attribute=False)
    
    return render(request, 'military_document.html', {'form': form})
```

I am not sure what you are doing in the doc.render(contect) etc., if you want to use `group_degree` in the render, you need to have `render` inside of `form.is_valid()`.